# How to describe the way you are going to talk with someone

Tags: english-to-german, preposition

In English, I would say something like, "would you like to speak on Skype".

Would that be:

> Würdest du über/auf/an Skype sprechen?

Would it be the same for talking on the phone?

Essentially I'm asking, which preposition should I use for using Skype or talking on the phone?

Comment: Is your question about how to invite somebody to talk (via any device) or are you asking which preposition to use with "Skype"?

Comment: Which preposition to use with skype. I'll modify the question to make it clearer

Comment: Most would turn Sype into a Verb: "Können wir skypen?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the case:

> übers Internet
>
> über Skype
>
> über Facebook
>
> über / per / via SMS, E-Mail, WhatsApp
>
> am Telefon / per Telefon / telefonisch
>
> per Post / auf dem Postweg / postalisch

Comment: "per" fits all.

Answer (score 2):

I would say *Können wir uns via Skype unterhalten?*

If you use *über Skype* it could also mean you want to talk *about* Skype. I would also use *unterhalten/reden* instead of *sprechen* but that's also correct.